# Links in Navbar are getting on top of each other when resizing the browser (I am using Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I am doing a double navbar in the website so when I resize the window the links in the second navbar go on top of each other like in amazon website

How can I make them resize with resizing the window and keeping them displayed horizontally like in amazon?

Here is the full code of the website:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#232f3d 460px, white) fixed;
}

.img{
    width: 100px;
}

a{
    color: white !important;
}

.navbar-nav{
    margin-left: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


#hehe a:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white !important;
    border: 1px solid white
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: black !important;
    background-color: white;
}

.d-flex{
    width: 600px;
} 

#drop{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.shopping-cart:hover{
    padding: 2px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
}



.shopping-cart{
    width: 40px !important;
}

.p2_landing{
    margin-top: -20px;

}

@media (max-width:992px){
    .navbar-nav{
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }

    .d-flex{
        margin-top: 4px; 
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    
    <!-- end links -->
    <title>Amazon</title>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Start Nav 1 -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark" >
        <div class="container ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <form class="d-flex ms-5 " role="search">
                <input class="form-control  rounded-0" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0 ">Search</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Log in</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/shopping-cart.png" class="shopping-cart" alt="shopping-cart">
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <!-- End nav 1 -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-transparent " id="hehe">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Kids</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Men</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Women</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Fragrances</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Toys & Games</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Electronics</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Today's Deals</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Clothes</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share complete code and/or screenshot how do you want your output

Comment: I can't display images becuase I don't have 10 reputation in  this website.. I want the links to be like in amazon website

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did not share the complete code I found the solution.

```
flex-direction: row;
```

add this to your `.navbar-nav` and it will be ok, but you need further changes on your code to fix the spacing.